# IIS does not start .net core 1.0 executable

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-1.0

so after .net core 1.0 got published I started a new console project and imported the code from a small prototype that is supposed to run without IIS. Besides having to use `net46` in my `project.json` due the not-yet updated `MongoDB.Driver`, that worked fine. When I build the app in Visual Studio a small `App.exe` with a lot of dll is build and can be run fine locally without IIS.

I then noticed the option to build for IIS Express and thought that I can use the IIS on our server (IIS 6.2, Windows Server 2012 R2) too. It publishes fine with WebDeploy, but nothing happens after that. I was following [this official guide](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/iis.html). I installed the .NET core Windows Server Hosting bundle and everything appears to be in order, but when I browse to the url, I get a ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`. The`app.exe`does not appear in the Task Manager and I can't find any log file, although it is enabled in the`web.config`. I can execute the app manually, but then it only listens on the default`localhost:5000` address.

If I understood it correctly, the IIS is supposed to act as a reverse-proxy to the `dotnet` tool which starts a `dll`, but in my case it's already a compiled `exe` that works standalone. But I can't figure out how to build a `dll` from this app..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You cannot only publish the binaries, ASP.NET Core module on IIS must also be installed and configured.

Comment: But how can build the `dll`? The ASP.NET Core module is installed and the Application Pool is set to `No Managed Code`..

Comment: if you have the module installed, post your web.config file.

Comment: @LexLi `web.config` looks like [this](http://pastebin.com/me9QNfTi)..

Comment: this config file looks perfectly fine - you have .exe because you target full framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you target full .NET Framework the application will be .exe and not .dll and it is fine. ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED indicates that the url you provided in your browser could not be resolved and the request to the application was not made. AspNet Core Module starts the application on the first request and because the host could not be resolved the request was not made and the application was not started. Once you figure out why the name could not be resolved and you still have issues with making your application work with IIS take a look [at my post](https://blog.3d-logic.com/2016/06/08/running-asp-net-core-applications-with-iis-and-antares/) which explains how things work and how to troubleshoot issues. This, however, only applies after the request can reach your application.